# Specify a dependency of `bin_PROGRAMS` without telling Automake how to build `bin_PROGRAMS`

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make, automake

So some of the `*.c` files that `bin_PROGRAMS` in my automake setup depend on a `no_common.h` that's generated by creating a symlink from `main.h`, now prior to some recent changes in my `Makefile.am` `no_common.h` was included in `bin_PROGRAMS` so that it'd get generated like it should be, but that also made it so that it'd get installed into `/usr/bin` alongside the binaries produced by `make`, which isn't what I want.

I know that I could just use something like this in my `Makefile.am` file:

```
$(bin_PROGRAMS): no_common.h
```

but wouldn't that mean I'd have to tell `make` exactly how I want `bin_PROGRAMS` to be built?  Would putting `no_common.h` back into `bin_PROGRAMS` and then adding it to `noinst_HEADERS` resolve this issue?

Can this be done, is there some other tricky trick that I could use, or am I simply asking for something that can't be done?

**NOTE**: I don't want to change the file `#include` from `no_common.h` to `main.h` in the affected files.  (Yes, I know I'm probably being picky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automake provides the `BUILT_SOURCES` variable to solve this problem.

A file mentioned in `BUILT_SOURCES` will be created early during `make` -- before any compilations.  However, no other dependency is implied; that is, the file is created but not compiled and not assumed to be a dependency of any other particular `.o`; which is just what you want.

So in your case you would simply do:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = no_common.h
```